# Scroll to Specific Div not working in Fancy box Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Fancy Box Popup , it has a long page which scrolls, but I want it to scroll up to the header Div on top of that popup when i click on **Go to top** button. How can i force it to scroll.

Here is my code for scrolling :

```
<script>
$('#goTop').click(function (){

     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(".wrap").offset().top}, 750);
     return false;

});
</script>
```

Why is it not scrolling, there are no errors in console , plus i have used the code on normal page , it works there . but it doesnot works in fancy box. Any solution ?

Here is the Image of my Popup :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried: `$('#modal-id').animate(...)`

Comment: Could you paste your HTML for the fancybox please.

Comment: fancybox provides mousewheel event whether you want it or not..you want to either adjust the options or the events..hope [this](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to scroll the actual modal window, not the document's `<body>`.

```
$('#goTop').click(function (){
    $(this).closest('.fancybox-inner').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 750);
    return false;
});
```

Where `fancybox-inner` is the class given to the fancybox which has a fixed height and CSS `overflow-y: scroll`.

Comment: .fancybox-inner is my class where i set the overflow-y: scroll

Comment: Can you tel me why you used : $(this).closest ?

Comment: If you have multiple fancyboxes, this will chose the one that the "scroll to top" button is in.

Comment: Can i use simple scroll ? i mean not ScrollTop

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.fancybox-overlay').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.fancybox-overlay').scrollTop() + $("#div").offset().top
});
```

Comment: Do you mind adding, at the very least, a small explanation regarding what your code does? It's readable, yes, but *why* does it work is always helpful =]